# Accessing to the element of DataFrame after applying groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Why I can’t access the element after applying groupby?
How can I do it?

When I write:
`data['item_price'][100]`,
then all is good: `Out[65]: 4.45` - it's a price of 100 good.

But after applying groupby it doesn't work:

```
total_prices = data.groupby('order_id')
total_prices['item_price'][100]
```

there's the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-f810d8e02df9> in <module>
      2 total_prices = data.groupby('order_id')
      3 
----> 4 total_prices['item_price'][100]
      5 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    256         if self._selection is not None:
    257             raise IndexError('Column(s) {selection} already selected'
--> 258                              .format(selection=self._selection))
    259 
    260         if isinstance(key, (list, tuple, ABCSeries, ABCIndexClass,

IndexError: Column(s) item_price already selected
```

But I still want to get access to the element.

Comment: can you give us some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply groupby, the indexes of the original DataFrame are not the same. All the elements with the same 'order_id' have been grouped together. Therefore, when you want a specific index, you can 1) select the group or 'order_id' or 2) the index of the 'item_price' for each group.

1. In order to do the first, you need to use `get_group` doing

   ```py
   total_prices['item_price'].get_group(5)
   ```

   and then select the element on the group that you want using `iloc` or `loc`

   ```py
   total_prices['item_price'].get_group(5).iloc[10]
   ```
2. The other option is to ask for an index for each group using `take`

   ```py
   total_prices['item_price'].take([10])
   ```

   This will return the 'item_price' 10 for each group. Then, you can use `iloc` or `loc` to get the value of the 'item_price' 10 for a specific 'order_id'

   ```py
   total_prices['item_price'].take([10]).iloc[5]
   ```

To find what group has the element you want, you can always use the dictionary

```py
total_prices['item_price'].groups
```

which relates every 'order_id' with the 'item_price' elements grouped in that 'order_id'.